# What are the factors affecting in "move_uploaded_file()" method

Tags: php, web-hosting

I used this method `move_uploaded_file()` in my script to upload files...,
Sometimes the images and files uploaded Successfully,
but sometimes the File upload process fails :(
....**Note:** the files' size smaller than `upload_max_filesize` in php.ini of my web host host,
So what is the factors or elements that affect on uploading process as  `upload_max_filesize`

IF `max_execution_time` or `memory_limit` or `.....` affect

Comment: Can you provide the code around your usage of move_uploaded_file? Without that its impossible to help you. We dont know what 'sometimes' means here, im assuming youre not programming a random number generator.

Comment: the code is very well .... I want to know only elements those affect on uploading process  as IF "max_execution_time" or "memory_limit" or .....  affect

Comment: My educated guess is that you don't verify the `error` key in `$_FILES` and invoke `move_uploaded_file()` even if the upload failed, thus the seemingly randomly failures.

Comment: @MedoElmasri why are you asking for help if you are not willing to provide details such as the **actual code which produces this problem?**  There could be numerous reasons: permission, file size, space on disc, file name, ... but all of this doesnt matter. Since your code is working, there should be no problem to adjust it to log meta data to the files that it can save and everything it cant save. Then you could try to see a pattern to figure out whats wrong... also make sure you are [displaying errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two of the reasons include:

1. Trying to write a file in a directory that has no write permission
2. Invalid file name that contains some special characters

You can also have a look at [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Is "max_execution_time" or "memory_limit" or ..... in the php.ini affect on uploading process

Comment: @MedoElmasri It's `move_uploaded_file()` (note the *uploaded* part). This function moves a file that has been already uploaded.